# Conversion format from time to default datetime

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have time as 1:00PM.I have to convert to format '1/1/1900 01:00:00 PM'.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(datetime , "1/1/1900 " + "1:00 PM" , 101)
```

Comment: Got one error as "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string."

Comment: the space in '1/1/1900 ' is significant. I hope you did not overlook it!

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1**: Let's get the date and save it into @Date variable.

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME;
SELECT @Date = CONVERT(DATETIME, '1:00PM' , 100);
```

Now @Date = 1900-01-01 13:00:00.000

**STEP 2**: Let's convert it into custom format

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Date, 101) + ' '
       + REPLACE(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Date, 131), 12, 14)),
       ':000', ' ');
```

This returns '1/1/1990 1:00:00 PM'

Comment: i need date format as 1/1/1900 1:00:00 PM.Now the result iam getting as 1900-01-01 13:00:00.000

Answer (score 0):

See "CAST and CONVERT" in sql server books online

dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM

you probably want 131
but return it as a varchar

so

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),131)
```